# iOs text length and computer text length different

Tags: ios, xcode, text, screen, display

So I'm trying to get some data from a website in my iOs project all is well but there are some spaces in this text.

Text looks like this in computer:

```
Em                                      Am
Sar beni, ben sana kendimi feda etmişim sev beni.
```

But when I try to show it in text view in iOs it turns into:

```
Em                  Am
Sar beni, ben sana kendimi feda etmişim sev beni.
```

I think the problem is with the display on the monitor and iOs device is there any solution to this?